# TSQL .modfy based on value from other node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have an xml

```
<questions>
    <question>
        <id>1</id>
        <text>question 1</text>
        <answer></answer>
    </question>
    <question>
        <id>2</id>
        <text>question 2</text>
        <answer></answer>
    </question>
</questions>
```

I want to add/modify answer node based on the id node. how do I call replace with using the id condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

```
SET @myDoc.modify('
   replace value of (/questions/question[id=1]/answer/text())[1]
   with     "MyAnswer"
')
```

Comment: just change capitalized ID to id, xml is case-sensitive, and accept your answer.